# Caching Data (imported and processed) in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a dashboard (using shinydashboard) that interfaces with the UNHCR data API but it is proving to be a bit too demanding in terms of computation. So I was wondering, is there a way to cache some of the demanding components and add a refresh option?

For instance, can I cache "JOR" and "population" below, and refresh them when needed? If yes, how?

```
JOR <- fromJSON("http://data.unhcr.org/api/population/search.json?name=JOR&level=country&instance_id=syria")
population <- JOR$population
```

Comment: You may like to take a look at the answer I provided to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026881/how-to-cache-data-in-shiny-server

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps .