# How to cache data in shiny server?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I am using R to deploy an app over the web, but the URL from which my app takes data is where my app takes time. Is it possible to cache that data?
I tried to install the packages memoise, R.cache and a few more that were all unsupported by the server.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend trying the [DataCache](http://jason.bryer.org/DataCache/) package by Jason Bryer. The package is available through GitHub and I was successful in using it today for a Shiny app that I am developing.

The main function from that package is `data.cache`. You will need to a define a function that generates a list of objects that you want to cache, and then pass the function you define as an argument to `data.cache`. I also recommend setting the `cache.name` parameter of `data.cache` if you intend on caching more than one list of objects in your application.

For example:

```
DataCache::data.cache(
  function(){
    list(
      normal_random_numbers = rnorm(10),
      uniform_random_numbers = runif(10)
    )
  },
  cache.name = 'my_random_numbers'
)
```

The above code creates two objects in the local environment, `normal_random_numbers` and `uniform_random_numbers`, as well as caches these to the file system. When you run this code again, the cached copies of these objects will be used rather than being regenerated - unless of course the cache expires. The `frequency` parameter of `data.cache` is used to set the expiry of the cache, which is set to `daily` by default.

If you are running the application under Windows then use [this slightly modified version](https://github.com/bplouvier/DataCache) of the package. This is to address--- a bug that is apparently due to the cache filename being incompatible with the Windows file system.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-caching.html) article from Rstudio is quite exhaustive and walks you through different ways to achieve that (i.e diskcache, the [`storr`](http://richfitz.github.io/storr/index.html) package or a Redis instance).

The main logic revolves around rendering a cached element and setting up the logic for cache invalidation:

```r
function(input, output) {
  renderCachedPlot(
    {
      # Code for a beautiful plot
    },
    # A change in the input or the dataframe will invalidate the cache
    cacheKeyExpr = list({ input$n, df() }) 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- In your global.R or server.R, set e.g.

```
shinyOptions(cache = cachem::cache_disk('./cache', max_n = 1000, logfile = './logs/appLog.txt', evict = 'fifo'))
```

- Set a (e.g.) "cache" directory inside the root of your app
- Give execute/read/write permissions for owner and owner's group to this directory

```
sudo chmode 764 cache
```

- Give ownership of this directory to shiny

```
sudo chown shiny:shiny cache
```

Moreover, I would recommend:

- Create a (e.g.) "logs" directory, dedicated to caching, inside the root of your app
- Create an empty "appLog.txt" file inside this directory
- Give read/write rights to "appLog.txt" file

```
sudo chmode 664 appLog.txt
```

- Give shiny ownership to log directory

```
sudo chown shiny:shiny logs
```

Otherwise, leave the dir argument in `cachem::cache_disk()` unchanged (i.e. NULL) and all cached objects will automatically go to a temp() directory over which you have little-to-no control.